# Parameters of dlib shape predictor model

Tags: python, computer-vision, training-data, dlib

I trained dlib shape predictor model on my custom data (using train_shape_predictor.py file). As a result I got .dat file. Now I have an image containing an object on which the dlib prediction model has been trained. How I will use that prediction model, to predict a shape in the input image?
I am seeing [Dlib shape prediction documentation](http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.shape_predictor), there is mentioned that dlib shape predictor accepts two arguments :

1. An image
2. A box (Dlib Rectangle)

Now what will be these parameters, in my case, as I have just one image (Containing an object, which will be predicted through trained model)?

Any sort of help in that regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the document says:

- image is a numpy ndarray containing either an 8bit grayscale or RGB
  image. --> Pass your image here
- box is the bounding box to begin the shape prediction inside. --> if you already have the bounding box of your object (e.g. where about a face is in the image), pass it here.

A typical application would be:

```
rects = dlib.simple_object_detector(image)

for rect in rects:
   shape = dlib.shape_predictor(image, rect)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use dlib object detector. Is there any other way, in which I wouldn't have to use dlib object detector? Can you please shed some light on that?

Comment: @user8611018 the shape predictor only wants an image frame and a dlib rectangle object to estimate the shape. Hence, if you don't want to use dlib object detector then in that case, first use your custom object detector and find the points (rmin, cmin) and (rmax, cmax) for the bounding box (r=row,c=col). Than cast them as dlib rectangle object like "dlib_rect = dlib.rectangle(rmin, cmin, rmax, cmax)" and now pass this rectangle object to shape_predictor object along with the image frame like "landmarks = pred_object(image, dlib_rect)" where pred_object = dlib.shape_predictor(r"some_model.dat")

Answer (score 1):

You can use any object detector for finding the bounding boxes. As Quang said, it's correct for dlib.

You can also use OpenCV's detector. However, you need to keep in mind that dlib's rectangle four coordinate and OpenCV rectangle representation is different.

After getting a bounding box from Opencv, do this.

```
d_rect = dlib.rectangle(left= o_rect[0] , top=o_rect[1], right=o_rect[2], bottom=o_rect[3])
```

where o_rect is OpenCV rectangle.